# How to add Spark dependencies from inside pyspark shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming-kafka

I'm working with Spark 2.3.1, Kafka 1.1 and python 2.7.9, and I'm not able to update it.

I've found a problem when I'm trying to use SparkStreaming to push (or pull) data from (to) Kafka. When I have no data in Kafka-queue (because it ends or because it never comes), Spark breaks after 4 tries

```
2020-02-10 12:52:51 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 172.21.0.4, executor 1): java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot fetch record for offset 4562638 in 120000 milliseconds
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$InternalKafkaConsumer$$fetchData(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer$$anonfun$get$1.apply(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer$$anonfun$get$1.apply(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThread.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThread.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.runUninterruptiblyIfPossible(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.get(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer$class.get(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer$CachedKafkaDataConsumer.get(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceRDD$$anon$1.getNext(KafkaSourceRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceRDD$$anon$1.getNext(KafkaSourceRDD.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:461)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:148)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

...x4

```
2020-02-10 12:58:52 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
2020-02-10 12:58:52 ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec:70 - Data source writer org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.InternalRowMicroBatchWriter@306b28ba is aborting.
2020-02-10 12:58:52 ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec:70 - Data source writer org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.InternalRowMicroBatchWriter@306b28ba aborted.
2020-02-10 12:58:52 ERROR MicroBatchExecution:91 - Query [id = 45351c37-ea34-414e-8712-52ab2adeb4d3, runId = b9ad9075-0b1e-419d-ac57-212d3d7fed71] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted.
```

I've found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49526632/using-spark-structured-streaming-to-read-data-from-kafka-issue-of-over-time-is), but I don't know how I can add this solution from inside PySpark shell

Comment: you can use: pyspark --packages ....

Comment: but with exclude option?

Comment: maybe can help you: `pyspark --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0`